# I bricked my BIOS. Can I Re-Flash it externally?

Tags: bios, hardware-failure, flash, lenovo-laptop

I was trying to fix my mom's computer by re-flashing the BIOS since her [Lenovo Yoga 710-11isk](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/yoga_710-11isk_710-11ikb_hmm_201608.pdf) laptop had been infected at the hardware level. However, the update failed and now the device won't turn on at all.

I have already opened it and looked for the BIOS chip but the only one I could find looked like a NIKOS flash chip which is not supported by the TL866 mini pro flasher or the Raspberry Pi flashrom utility. Is there any way to flash it still without the flasher's support for it?

Comment: Send it to a Lenovo Service center.

Comment: Tried that, however they said since its out of warranty they will not reflash or replace the chip even if I paid for it. Cruddy customer service if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Sad story is that you *probably* could have recovered it if you hadn't let it power off.

On the bright side; there's a last ditch effort that *may* allow you to try again.

If you open the laptop, and remove the RTC battery inside, and leave it out for some 24hrs. Then put it back. The BIOS *may* return to it's former self. Make sure all power to the laptop is disconnected, as well as remove the "power" battery for the laptop.

Good luck!

Comment: Not a possibility, I am sure it was a bad flash that corrupted the image, if one byte is off the BIOS is not going to boot. I am pretty sure these cheap Chinese manufacturers built this board will not use a recognizable BIOS and tracking down chip specifications will be nearly impossible. Thanks for all the suggestions though!